# A lambda's return type can be deduced by the return value, so why can't a function's?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, auto

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    auto lambda = [] {
        return 7;
    };

    std::cout << lambda() << '\n';

}
```

This program compiles and prints 7.
The return type of the lambda is deduced to the integer type based on the return value of 7.

---

Why isn't this possible with ordinary functions?

```
#include <iostream>

auto function(){
    return 42;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << function() << '\n';
}
```

**error: ‘function’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type**

Comment: **Already available in VS2013 Nov CTP.** It's a C++14 feature already available. It's an awesome help for templated functions with messy return types.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[C++14 has this feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Function_return_type_deduction). You can test it with new versions of GCC or clang by setting the `-std=c++1y` flag.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fa0e28a0ec36281)

In addition to that, in C++14 you can also use `decltype(auto)` (which mirrors `decltype(auto)` as that of variables) for your function to deduce its return value using `decltype` semantics.

An example would be that for forwarding functions, for which `decltype(auto)` is particularly useful:

```
template<typename function_type, typename... arg_types>
decltype(auto) do_nothing_but_forward(function_type func, arg_types&&... args) {
    return func(std::forward<arg_types>(args)...);
}
```

With the use of `decltype(auto)`, you mimic the actual return type of `func` when called with the specified arguments. There's no more duplication of code in the trailing return type which is very frustrating and error-prone in C++11.

Comment: Why `decltype(auto)` and not just `auto`?

Comment: @dashesy `auto` uses template type deduction - the same is used when calling function templates, which means it strips adornments like `&` - reference. `decltype(auto)` - uses decltype rules for type deduction - which means it infers the same type as the expression passed to it.

Answer (score 25):

This is just a limitation of how the language was created and has evolved. In the upcoming C++14 standard the return type of a function can be deduced in some contexts, although not in all. There are complications when there are multiple return statements.

Additionally, deduced return types have other issues, for example, the return type of a template function cannot be used in a [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) context, as to be able to deduce the type, the compiler must instantiate the function template, which happens *after* substitution. The net result is that while the feature will be there in the near future, I would avoid it if you can provide the type yourself.

Comment: *"This is just a limitation of how the language was created and has evolved."* - Of course it is, +1 for that alone.

Answer (score 10):

This is coming in c++14. See the following [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html).

Answer (score 6):

Its not there still.. its gonna be in C++1y/C++14.. check out this [link of feature](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it's probably because **type-inferred lambdas can't be recursive**.

Why does this matter? Because if a type-inferred lambda could be recursive (by "type-inferred" I mean where the variable's name is of type `auto`), then its return type could potentially depend on itself -- and while this is sometimes possible to solve, it much more difficult to implement than "simple" type inference. I'm not even sure if it's *always* solvable (is it decidable in the general case?). If functions supported type inference, though, this issue would have to be taken care of, so it's likely that they just excluded them for this reason.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @BryanChen: Sure, I explained a bit more.

Comment: This is not a point of difference between lambdas and function definitions. Even plain objects can specify circular dependency, `auto x = x * 2;`. In all cases it is simply prohibited.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Uh, are you sure the meaning of `auto x = x * 2` is even defined?

Comment: @Mehrdad It's prohibited. Same as a self-referential lambda. That is my point.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Sorry I don't get your point. Functions are inherently allowed to be recursive, so I was saying that they would have to remove that possibility if they also wanted to allow for return type inference.

Comment: Lambdas and functions are allowed to be recursive, and variable initialization is allowed to be self-referential, but `auto` is ill-formed if there is a cyclic dependency.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That is a correct sentence but none of it contradicts anything I've said... I said type-inferred (aka `auto`) lambdas can't be recursive, which is correct. I said functions can be recursive, which is correct. I said functions whose return types are inferred can't be recursive, which I believe is also correct. You seem to be talking about something completely orthogonal here...

Comment: Your assertion in this answer is that recursion potentially poses a problem in conjunction with `auto`. My response is that this is true, but they already solved the problem by simply forbidding you to do the wrong thing. There is no reason functions should be different from lambdas, and in C++14 they won't be.